# How to return only those customer_id who visited Santa Clara after visiting Milpitas or #5 after visiting #2

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

```
Customer_ID  Region    Location      Store_Entry
--------------------------------------------------------
   D1          2       Milpitas      '2020-10-01' 14:03
   D2          5       Santa Clara   '2020-10-01' 15:16
   D2          5       Santa Clara   '2020-10-01' 16:00
   D3          4       Milpitas      '2020-10-01' 16:12
   D1          3       Los Gatos     '2020-10-01' 16:23
   D2          2       Milpitas      '2020-10-01' 17:01
```

How can I return the `customer_id` of those customers who visited Santa Clara after visiting Milpitas or #5 after visiting #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select customer_id
from t
where location in ('Santa Clara', 'Milpitas')
group by customer_id
having max(store_entry) filter (where location = 'Santa Clara') >
       min(store_entry) filter (where location = 'Milpitas');
```

Your statement is that the customer when to *after* Santa Clara *after* Milpitas.  This leaves open the possibility that the customer visited both locations multiple times.

To meet the condition as stated, you need to know that some visit to Santa Clara was later than some visit to Milpitas (at least that is how I interpret the question).  Well, that is true if the *lastest* visit to Santa Clara was after the *earliest* visit to Milpitas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I get the output but I would really appreciate it if you enlighten me here because it's a little confusing to me why we choose max for Milpitas and min for Santa Clara? why it's not simply like Milipitas > Santa Clara.. Would love to hear from you. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Guru . . . I read the question wrong.  I fixed the logic and explained the reasoning.

Comment: @Guru . . . Is there is a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: I think I accepted your answer, I think because I accepted both the answer that's why you are not able to see them. I apologize!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (Customer_ID)
WHERE t1.Location = 'Santa Clara'
  AND t2.Location = 'Milpitas'
  AND t1.Store_Entry > t2.Store_Entry
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I get the output but I would really appreciate it if you enlighten me here because it's a little confusing to me why we are choosing min/max store entry time here? Because there is a possibility that the customer first visited Santa Clara then Mlipitas then again Santa Clara or vice versa .. so in a single day what if he visited both the places multiple times? Would love to hear from you. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Guru *why we are choosing min/max store entry time here?* Where you have found MIN() or MAX()??? Times compare simply checks that *who visited Santa Clara after visiting Milpitas*

Comment: Sorry, my bad .. the question was something like why we are not using MIN() or MAX()..

Comment: We're not interested in selection of definite row combination or in counting - we need onry relative times matching. So single values are compared. If any pair which matches all conditions is found, we select according customer.

Answer (score 0):

Query For mySQL 8.0

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LEAD(region) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id, store_entry) AS next_region
    FROM tour_tab
)
SELECT customer_id
FROM cte
WHERE region=5 AND next_region=2 /* 'Santa Clara' AND 'Milpitas' */
```